# JavaScript fast lookup data structure?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of 109582 strings ordered alphabetically. My web application will be making a lot of rapid checks for whether a given string is contained in the array. Obviously I could make a wrapper class that is a hash table or binary tree, but is there any native JavaScript data structure that I can use instead?

Comment: Binary search perhaps?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure. Make an dictionary object

```
dict = {
  string1: 1,
  string2: 1,
etc
```

It's guaranteed to provide O(1) lookup time.

Comment: This is definitely the fastest. if (dict[string])

Comment: Big O notation isn't the only concern.  Wall-time measurements matter to.  I'd suggest that the OP time to test if using one hash/object is better, or if he should at least create a hash for each  first letter.

Comment: Nothing does actually guarantee `O(1)` lookup time. True, most implementations do use hash maps for objects, but they could choose anything else as well.

Comment: Is this would be faster than using an Array?

Answer (score 10):

There are various suitable structures and approaches, see below how they perform.

##### Array

- `for` loop
- `for` loop (reversed)
- `array.includes(target)`

##### Set

- `set.has(target)`

##### Object

- `obj.hasOwnProperty(target)`
- `target in obj` **<- fastest**
- `obj[target]` **<- fastest**

##### Map

- `map.has(target)`

##### Results from **January 2024, Chrome 121**

What is interesting in this result is that `map.has` has suddenly gotten slower to same speed of `set.has`.
[image]

##### Results from **February 2022, Chrome 98**

[image]

##### Results from **January 2021, Chrome 87**

[image]

---

*This answer is migrated from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65604244/985454*

Comment: It's worth noting that while `map` is indeed slower, you can map `<any*>:<any*>`, while Object only allows `<string>:<any*>`  _(I know the question is specific to string, but since your answer is so thorough I couldn't help but highlight the reason behind map' performance tradeoff )_