# Javascript set vs array vs object definition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set

I'm unclear about what the differences between Set and Array are in Javascript (other than Set is new in ES6). Why would you use Set instead of Array or an Object definition.

Why was Set introduced?

Comment: Set doesn't allow duplicate values

Comment: does it error or anything if you try?

Comment: No, nothing happens because you already have that value. Have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k2gc0p58/). Also read the MDN docs, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Every value in a set has to be unique, but in Array you can push same value as many times as you'd like.

"Set objects are collections of values. You can iterate through the elements of a set in insertion order. A value in the Set may only occur once; it is unique in the Set's collection."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Removing values, interestingly enough, when dealing with small amounts of data, there isn't much performance difference between the two (Array and Set), but when you start to deal with big data, removal is a lot faster in Sets vs Arrays.

Adding values to Array is 4 times faster than adding them to set.

Iterating through the values Array is here also better performer (Growing exponentially based on the amount of data).

You can read more about the performance differences at;
[Javascript Set vs. Array performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007637/javascript-set-vs-array-performance)

"At 10k elements, both tests ran comparable times (array: 16.6 ms, set: 20.7 ms) but when dealing with 100k elements, the set was the clear winner (array: 1974.8 ms, set: 83.6 ms) but only because of the removing operation. Otherwise the array was faster. I couldn't say exactly why that is."

Count unique items in object Set Vs Object write-up https://github.com/anvaka/set-vs-object

TL:DR  Set is almost two times faster than Object.

**Why Set was introduced (My guess)?**

There are sometimes when you need an easy way to build up a collection of values and you have to make sure each value is unique. This brings a lot overhead away from the old fashioned check if array has the value or not and then push or skip.

This scenario was not covered in the performance post I linked earlier, but doing fast experiment on Array of 10,000 items and then adding 15 items where 5 were duplicates to the combined collection, adding to array with checking for duplicate values and skipping if duplicate it took 74ms and with set just using the set.add(value) it took 9ms.

**When would you need this?**

One real life example that came to my mind is that if you have an email marketing letter and you for example would have options;
 - TV
 - Music
 - Movies
 - Sports

One day your client or you would like to have only one email option for TV, Music and Movies called "Entertainment". You would need to build up a new collection based on the data from these 3 different values and you would need to make sure each email are added to the new entertainment emailing list only once. Meaning that users could've opted-in for Movies as well as TV if they are interested in both.

Here you could just make set Entertainment and then iterate through all the lists TV/Music/Movies and use Entertainment.add(email) and the set would take care of skipping values that already exists in the list. Hence avoiding duplicate emails in the emailing list.

Also set would be optimal format to store your email subscriber addresses, as nobody could accidentally opt-in twice for you emails.

Comment: So its ONLY better to use Sets when removing alot of items. otherwise Arrays win in your performance example? Also doesn't anwser why its needed / was introduced

Comment: Recommend Chapter 7 of Understanding ECMAScript 6 for discussion of the motivation for sets and maps.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, set is used to store elements uniquely whereas in arrays, you can duplicate the elements. And regarding objects, in use cases when you also need to store additional information regarding each element, then you would choose object over set and array.

For example: storing info. of your apps users, which include their name, phone no., address, email etc.
Then in objects, you can define a key, let's say email (or you could also create a unique id), then keys in your object would be email (or the other one) and the additional info about the user would get stored as properties.