# When to use Set in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, set, indexof

I'm just a beginner in javaScript and have a background in python. I was trying this exercise to check if every character of the *string2* is contained within the *string1*.
For example, if *string1* is "hello", I'll return `true` if *string2* is "leh" and `false` if *string2* is "low".

What I came up was this:

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var set = new Set(string1.split(''));
  for (var i = 0; i < string2.length; i++)
    if (!set.has(string2[i]))
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

I could also go about converting string2 into a `Set` and then do take the difference i.e. the operation of `set(string2) - set(string1)` which will fetch me the set of characters that are in String2 but not in String1 but I read creating a set is costly so I didn't go ahead.

I checked other solutions and everyone was using `string1.indexOf(letter)` method for checking if every letter in string2 is there in string1 or not.

I want to know when should one use a `Set` difference. Why everyone is using `array.indexOf()` method which costs O(n) instead of `set.has()` method which is O(1). Are there any pitfalls if I'm using `set.has()`. (say browser compatibility)?

Any recommendation is helpful.

Comment: just curious, how are you determining the the runtimes of set.has() and array.indexOf()?

Comment: "*I read creating a set is costly so I didn't go ahead.*" - where did you read that?

Comment: Did you have any look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Browser_compatibility or https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Set?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will find more details and browser compatibility on [MDN - Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). For implementation of a Set in general, you can read [Set - Implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)#Implementations) on Wikipedia.

> Implementations described as "general use" typically strive to
>   optimize the `element_of`, `add`, and `delete` operations.

You can also check some test results on the [Array vs Set asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46190569/1222409) on Stack Overflow.

---

To answer your question, although the `has` operation might be a bit faster than using String's `indexOf` (or `includes`), in your specific case the cost of instantiating a new `Set` for each comparison is much greater.

I created a simple test with the following two methods:

```
function existsSet(str1, str2) {
  const set = new Set(str1);
  return ![...str2].some(char => !set.has(char));
}

function existsString(str1, str2) {
  return ![...str2].some(char => !str1.includes(char));
}
```

I called the above methods for 1 million randomly created strings and I got the following results:

```
existsSet: 1.29s
existsString: 0.47s
```

That's almost three times slower for the method that instantiates a `Set`.

---

You can find the test I run on the following JsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mspyratos/zwx3zcx1/11/

Answer (score 3):

In programming, multiple ways lead to the same solution. Using a set with `.has()` is just as valid as using `indexOf()`, it all depends on the surrounding code, and the re-use of the objects (eg: sets) you do.

Usually using `indexOf()` is faster on the CPU and does not care of the special characters (while a traditional simple split implies that words are separated by always the same character).

Building a set cost a little bit more. But it is still *pretty fast* so it should not be that much of a consideration.

In the end, do what your instinct tells you to do so that your code stays consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Let say we have:

```
const arr = [0,0,1,1]
const mySet = new Set()

mySet.add(arr)
```

`mySet.size` returns the number of unique elements in an array. Therefore it can be used to check for duplicate elements by comparing it to the length of the array.