# JavaScript: How come map.has is so much faster than set.has and array.indexOf?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, benchmarking, v8

I came across the following benchmarks: https://jsperf.com/array-includes-and-find-methods-vs-set-has
If you'll execute it, you'll see that `map.has` is by far the most efficient way of finding an item in a collection in the browser.

I also recreated this test in Node using `benchmarks.js`, and got the following results:

Node 9.4.0:

```
set.has x 6,454,428 ops/sec ±1.25% (90 runs sampled)
map.has x 64,519,657 ops/sec ±0.95% (86 runs sampled)
arr.includes x 11,415,721 ops/sec ±1.41% (87 runs sampled)
arr.indexOf x 11,344,587 ops/sec ±1.39% (87 runs sampled)
arr.find x 1,579,635 ops/sec ±1.09% (92 runs sampled)
Fastest is map.has
```

Node 6.2.0:

```
set.has x 16,677,473 ops/sec ±1.35% (86 runs sampled)
map.has x 15,089,503 ops/sec ±1.35% (85 runs sampled)
arr.includes x 1,345,019 ops/sec ±1.31% (89 runs sampled)
arr.indexOf x 15,943,213 ops/sec ±4.40% (80 runs sampled)
arr.find x 1,423,994 ops/sec ±2.05% (82 runs sampled)
Fastest is set.has,arr.indexOf
```

These results are very surprising for me, does anyone know:

1. How come `map.has` is 10 times faster than `set.has` and almost 6 times faster than `array.indexOf`?
2. In Node 6, `includes` seems to be much slower than `indexOf`, and `arr.find(val => val === 1)` is the same as `arr.includes(1)`. Why?
3. `set.has` seems to be slower in Node 9 than it used to be in Node 6, why is that?

Comment: Because a `Set` is implemented as a hash set, which doesn't need to do linear search? That's the whole purpose of using it over a list structure.

Comment: `has` of `Map`   and `indexOf`  do two complelty differnt things. `indexOf`  searches for a value (that might exists multible times in an array). And `has` for an `key`  that has to be unique.

Comment: Thanks guys! but still, why `Map.has` is ten times faster than `Set.has`?

Comment: @EliranPe'er Yeah, that's weird. Also the performance degradation from node 6 to node 9. You might want to report it as a bug.

Comment: Will do, unless of course someone will supply a reasonable explanation here :) Thanks

Comment: You always have to be a little careful with this kind of test. Current JS Engines make runtime optimizations of the code, based on how the code runs over time. Tests that are performed with jspref or similar are usually very artificial and therefore it may be possible to "only" detect a certain weakness of the optimizer that would not be noticeable in a normal application. I am not saying that there is no problem here, only that this type of test should always be considered with some caution.

Comment: Definitely agree @t.niese

Comment: as @t.niese already said you should compare `mapVariable.has()` with `objectVariable.hasOwnProperty()` or `someIndex< arrayVariable.length`. Then you would not be surprised by difference in results.

Comment: @skyboyer How come `set.has` is much slower than?...

Comment: ...than `Array.indexOf()`? I'm not sure. Probably different data structure. Probably `Set.prototype.has()` checks also current object's prototype while `Array.indexOf()` does not.

Comment: No, how come `Map.has` is way faster than `Set.has`?

Comment: None of them should be significantly faster then the other. Because both should use the same way of hashing and lookup. So the results of `6.2.0` for `has`  is what I would expect. At the end of 2017 they closed [JS Maps and Sets Performance](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5717#c40), but when those changes in v8 are included into node [Performance regression in v8.10 and v9.0 for Maps with object keys](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19769) depends on when node updates v8.

Comment: if the question is just finding an item in a list, by far the quickest way is [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), being more efficient than ``OBJECT.hasOwnProperty()`` or ``MAP.has()``, but it's not a method

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**

Now V8 has `ReduceSetPrototypeHas` method, so it would be optimized in newer version of Node.js or browsers.

https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/4c81827c8d6ca1d3d9b0cb6a2ef1264eb0f59524

---

**TL;DR**: V8's TurboFan currently optimize Map.has() call into native method call in C++ world, but not Set.has() call.

> No, how come Map.has is way faster than Set.has?

This is also very interesting, because they must use the same internal implementation of hash table.

The answer dives into how **TurboFan**, JIT compiler of V8, does optimization. It utilizes **Sea of nodes** concept, you can think it is AST for
optimization. V8 does optimization by replacing some subtree in the sea of nodes with faster representation (**reduction**). Simplest example of reduction is replacing `a = 1 + 2` to `a = 3`.

One of the super power of this would be that it can replace some JS method calls with a call to underlying C++ implementations to remove overhead. See the official slide, especially a few pages from [this link](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1sOEF4MlF7LeO7uq-uThJSulJlTh--wgLeaVibsbb3tc/edit#slide=id.g5499b9c42_089) to see examples of what it does.

Then, look into the code where actual reduction happens.

In [js-call-reducer.cc](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/65d9c441dfad3d06d5a2cf2857a71e2388e10d6f/src/compiler/js-call-reducer.cc#L7223) of V8, `JSCall` of `Map.has` will be replaced with native function calls:

```
Reduction JSCallReducer::ReduceMapPrototypeHas(Node* node) {
  ...(reading current nodes)...

  Node* table = effect = graph()->NewNode(
      simplified()->LoadField(AccessBuilder::ForJSCollectionTable()), receiver,
      effect, control);

  Node* index = effect = graph()->NewNode(
      simplified()->FindOrderedHashMapEntry(), table, key, effect, control);

  Node* value = graph()->NewNode(simplified()->NumberEqual(), index,
                                 jsgraph()->MinusOneConstant());
  value = graph()->NewNode(simplified()->BooleanNot(), value);

  ReplaceWithValue(node, value, effect, control);
  return Replace(value);
}
```

(`FindOrderedHashMapEntry` is tied to `FindOrderedHashTableEntry` family methods which actually looks up the hash table. Look source code from [here](http://%20https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/65d9c441dfad3d06d5a2cf2857a71e2388e10d6f/src/builtins/builtins-collections-gen.cc#L2403).)

But **there is no `ReduceSetPrototypeHas` method**, so such optimization is not done for `Set.has`. This is why `Set.has()` is slower than `Map.has()`.

I confirmed that local-built V8 with replacing to below code makes `Set.has` and `Map.has` benchmark result almost the same.

```
Reduction JSCallReducer::ReduceMapPrototypeHas(Node* node) {
  return NoChange();
}
```

I'm not sure whether `Set.has` should be optimized or not, because V8 should optimize for **real-world application**, not for micro-benchmark result. (I also don't know what is and how large the drawback for adding new reduction.)

(I have no idea why upgrading Node 6.2.0 -> 9.4.0 make `Set.has()` 3 times slower.)

See https://v8.dev/docs/turbofan for further resources of TurboFan internals.

Comment: Someone please mark this answer as the correct one. The value is insane.