# Searching an array of strings in a file

Tags: node.js, arrays, nlp, full-text-search, stringtokenizer

I have a text file say, `testFile.txt` and an array of strings to be searched in the file as say, `['year', 'weather', 'USD 34235.00', 'sportsman', 'ಕನ್ನಡ']`. I can break the file into tokens with [NodeJS natural](https://www.npmjs.com/package/natural) and maybe, create a **large** array (~100-200x the number of entries in the string array) out of it. Then, sort both the arrays and start the search. Or, use `lodash` directly?

A `Found` result is when at least one string from the search string array is found in the text file; else, it should be considered as `NotFound`.

What are some of the options to implement such a search?

Comment: I think this can help: https://dev.to/akhilpokle/the-algorithm-behind-ctrl-f-3hgh

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest using `Set` for large array of tokens, then iterate through the search terms array, check if the tokens set `has` one of those terms. If the terms array is also large, you could considers using `Set` for that ([MDN docs for Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set))

You could see the performance comparision between array and set in context of large number of elements, from this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39010462/6655160)

Below is the demo snippet

```js
const tokens1 = ['ಕನ್ನಡ', 'asdasd', 'zxczxc', 'sadasd', 'wqeqweqwe', 'xzczxc']
const tokens2 = ['xzczcxz', 'asdqwdaxcxzc', 'asdxzcxzc', 'wqeqwe', 'zxczcxzxcasd']
const terms = ['year', 'weather', 'USD 34235.00', 'sportsman', 'ಕನ್ನಡ']

const set1 = new Set(tokens1)
const set2 = new Set(tokens2)

const find = (tokensSet, termsArray) => {
  for (const term of termsArray) {
    if (tokensSet.has(term)) {
      return 'Found'
    }
  }
  return 'Not Found'
}

console.log(find(set1, terms))
console.log(find(set2, terms))
```