# Javascript count unique values of object property in an object array

Tags: javascript

How do I calculate the unique values of an object property when I have an array of objects?

```
let organisations = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "nameOne",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "nameTwo",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "nameOne",
  }
]
```

In this case, how do I calculate the number of unique organisation names. The answer here is two, because there are two unique names.

This doesn't work

```
 var counts = this.filteredExtendedDeals.reduce(
        (organisations, name) => {
          counts[name] = (counts[name] || 0) + 1;
          return counts;
        },
        {}
      );
      return Object.keys(counts);
```

Comment: reduce or filter

Comment: @mplungjan You didn't specify an issue with the question but if its the lack of an attempt, that is now included

Comment: The attempt does not make any sense. You are not running on the same object you show and you are returning outside a function. Please make a [mcve] using the snippet editor.

Comment: You can use map with a Set: `new Set(organisations.map(({name}) => name)).size;`

Comment: Reduce, no set needed: `const names =  organisations.reduce((acc,org) => { if (acc.includes(org.name)) return acc; acc.push(org.name); return acc},[])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could reduce the list into a `Set` and then grab the `size`.

```js
const organisations = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "nameOne" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "nameTwo" },
  { "id": 3, "name": "nameOne" }
];

const uniqueItems = (list, keyFn) => list.reduce((resultSet, item) =>
    resultSet.add(typeof keyFn === 'string' ? item[keyFn] : keyFn(item)),
  new Set).size;

console.log(uniqueItems(organisations, 'name'));
console.log(uniqueItems(organisations, ({ name }) => name));
```

If you want to also filter-out `null` and `undefined` values:

```js
const organisations = [
  { "id": 1, "name": null },
  { "id": 2, "name": "nameTwo" },
  { "id": 3, "name": undefined }
];

const uniqueItemsNonNull = (list, keyFn) => list.reduce((resultSet, item) =>
    (v => v !== null && v !== undefined ? resultSet.add(v) : resultSet)
    (typeof keyFn === 'string' ? item[keyFn] : keyFn(item)),
  new Set).size;

console.log(uniqueItemsNonNull(organisations, 'name'));
console.log(uniqueItemsNonNull(organisations, ({ name }) => name));
```

Comment: Why set? `const names =  organisations.reduce((acc,org) => { if (acc.includes(org.name)) return acc; acc.push(org.name); return acc},[])`

Comment: @mplungjan A `Set` is more efficient than checking `Array` item indices. The lookup is O(1).

Comment: Interesting read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007637/javascript-set-vs-array-performance

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl what if i also do not want to include where name property is empty string. only those that have values?

Comment: @chitgoks I added an alternative version to filter-out `null` and `undefined` values. I used IIFE syntax to pass the evaluated value i.e. `v` into an expression.