# JavaScript convert for loops to ES6/ES7

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm asking little naive question, but I'm seriously I'm not sure how to convert this for loops

```
const filteredData = csiList.filter(item => {
        for (var i = 0, len = this.tableData.length; i < len; i++) {
          if (this.tableData[i].csiId == item.appId) {
            return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
      })
```

If some one can quickly show how this loops are/is written in more next gen JS ES6/ES7 way, would be of great help

Comment: `this.tableData` is an array, right? (as opposed to an [array-like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#working_with_array-like_objects) object)

Comment: [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Consider using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of a for loop inside a filter?

Comment: @Samathingamajig Yes its an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to make this more modern code, each step I show here is a based upon the previous:

#1 Use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops instead of manually using an index variable (also use `const` since this never changes during the same iteration)

```js
const filteredData = csiList.filter((item) => {
  for (const data of this.tableData) {
    if (data.csiId == item.appId) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
});
```

#2 Use [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to just get the necessary data (this is an opinion of if it's better or not, but I'm using more modern features since that's what you have asked for)

```js
const filteredData = csiList.filter(({ appId }) => {
  for (const { csiId } of this.tableData) {
    if (csiId == appId) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
});
```

#3 Use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), built for finding if at least one item in a list meets a criteria. Inverted here with `!`, since it returns `true` if at least one items meets the criteria. (Alternatively, use `every` with `!==`)

```js
const filteredData = csiList.filter(({ appId }) => {
  return !this.tableData.some(({ csiId }) => csiId === appId);
});
```

#4 Use the implicit return of an arrow function with `{` and `}` (on a new line because the width of each line is limited to 80 characters by [Prettier](https://prettier.io/)'s opinionated standard)

```js
const filteredData = csiList.filter(
  ({ appId }) => !this.tableData.some(({ csiId }) => csiId === appId),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how big your lists are but the solution using .some is O(mn). Meaning you're cycling through your tableData list multiple times.

Faster would be using a Set(). This solution would be O(n).

```js
(() => {

const tableData = [{ csiId: 1 }, { csiId: 2 }, { csiId: 4 }];
const csiList = [{ appId: 1 }, { appId: 3 }, { appId: 4 }];

const keepers = new Set(tableData.map((data) => data.csiId));
const filteredData = csiList.filter((obj) => keepers.has(obj.appId));
    
console.log(filteredData);

})();
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that using a set is generally not faster for small arrays (iterating through is faster than hashing and lookup) or when you're not using the set enough times (when creating the set is more expensive than just using the list), however this is probably on the scale of Doesn't Matter™. Remember, big o tells you the shape of how a function scales in space/time as input increases, it doesn't tell you what algorithm is faster for a certain number of inputs.

Comment: That's why I stated at top "I'm not sure how big your lists are".

Comment: This topic is covered in depth on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007637/javascript-set-vs-array-performance

Answer (score -1):

```
const filteredData = csiList.filter(item => !this.tableData.some(tableDataItem => tableDataItem.csiId === item.appId));
```

Comment: Nice one-liner, but this would benefit from an explanation for the OP